# MySQL After Insert trigger - how to handle case where no rows were inserted

Tags: mysql

UPDATED based on Akina's answer -

In MySQL the After Insert trigger fires for every insert call, even in cases where the insert fails and no rows are inserted. While any changes made by the trigger are rolled-back by MySQL on failure, external service calls made by the trigger may cause changes that need to also be rolled back.

Is there a way to catch this edge case in the trigger so it can be handled?

For ref my general trigger format is -

```
CREATE TRIGGER `db`.`table_name_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

-- HANDLE ERRORS
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
    get diagnostics condition 1
      @p1 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
      @p2 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
      @p3 = MYSQL_ERRNO,
      @p4 = SCHEMA_NAME,
      @p5 = TABLE_NAME;
    INSERT INTO `db_errors_table_name` (`location`, `error`)
        VALUES ('Some descriptive text here regarding loc', @p1);
END;

-- Call external service here

END
```

Comment: I suspect your premise that "Insert trigger fires for every insert call, even in cases where the insert fails" may not be true. Can you give an example?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that with a simple example it's not! I'll keep troubleshooting and remove this if it isn't a real thing. (I may have been initially biased when my search turned up the fact that SQL Server worked this way https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic610898-149-1.aspx)

Comment: @mustaccio see Akina's excellent example below; the trigger is called, but then all db changes rolled back (a bit my too simple try yesterday missed). Since the trigger I'm working with calls an external service there are external effects that can't be rolled back. I'm looking for a way to only call the external service if the trigger will be successfully committed.

Answer (score 2):

> the After Insert trigger fires for every insert call, even in cases where the insert fails and no rows are inserted

That's not right.

Single query is a transaction, trigger action is a part of it, if fail the whole transaction is rollbacked, including changes made by trigger.

> ```
> create table test (id int not null primary key, val int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table log(id int, val int, cnt int not null auto_increment primary key);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create trigger tr after insert on test for each row 
> insert into log (id, val) values (new.id, new.val);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into test values (1,1), (2,2);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |   1
>  2 |   2
> ```

> ```
> select * from log;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val | cnt
> -: | --: | --:
>  1 |   1 |   1
>  2 |   2 |   2
> ```

> ```
> insert into test 
> select 3,3 union all select 2,4 union all select 5,5 order by 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
> ```

> ```
> select * from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |   1
>  2 |   2
> ```

> ```
> select * from log;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val | cnt
> -: | --: | --:
>  1 |   1 |   1
>  2 |   2 |   2
> ```

> ```
> insert into log (id, val) values (6,6);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from log;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val | cnt
> -: | --: | --:
>  1 |   1 |   1
>  2 |   2 |   2
>  6 |   6 |   4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e8bfc387ec273e9a96d4f4d217b6a72)*

Pay attention to the hole in `log.cnt` values. Autoincrement value `3` is absent because it was used during 2nd insertion and then it was removed during rollback caused by duplicate error.

Comment: Oh! This makes sense with what we're seeing if I'm reading this right. So the trigger is executed, but then rolled back. So if the trigger called external code, in our case an AWS Lambda, then changes made by the Lambda would be maintained. Sound right?

Comment: No. Transactions don't care what, where, or what code changes. All changes made by the process will be rolled back regardless of where the code is located.